# Descendent selectors are slow?

Tags: html, css

When I have read about faster css selectors, I have notice `IDs` and `Classes` are faster than any other. Also, browsers match your `CSS Selectors` from **Right** to **Left**. That is, the most specific selector first.

So the author said *Do not attach any descendents to the classes; IDs.*

However, when I have read the source code of Facebook and Twitter, I have found them using CSS this way: `.uiInfoTable .label .annotation{color:#999}'`, `.big-photo-permalink .tweet .tweet-timestamp{// some css}`

When these selectors are slow, why don't they simply use `.annotation{color:#999}` instead of such a long selector, or if the class is available to both tags, then why not create a new class and add those CSS?

Is there anything I should know about descendent selectors? Do they have impact on performance of CSS selectors?

Comment: Because not everybody follows every guideline there is? I personally think the whole "do not ever use descendant selectors" thing is baseless. You have bigger problems if you need to avoid descendant selectors because they're actually slowing down your page.

Comment: @BoltClock but everybody follows the performace I guess? if they dont worry about the speed people stops using it?

Comment: @BoltClock if I avoid descedant selectors it slows downs the page? Could you explain me in detail or tutorial that helps me in finding the answer. any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Twitter and Facebook care more about saving lines on their code files than using best practices.

Comment: Can you post the link of mentioned article?

Comment: I think that there's a important difference between "avoid insanely" and "avoid when not needed specify" descendant selectors. Many times you have to use them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, the performance hit is practically zero. However if you start building more complex stylesheets, that "almost zero" can add up to something quite big.

Personally, I like to use the `>` combinator whenever I can. `.menu>li` is better than `.menu li` for example because the engine only has to look up one level instead of going all the way to the top every time.

Another upside of `>` is that it's clearly-defined. Imagine this:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item with submenu
        <ul>
            <li>Item 3.1</li>
            <li>Item 3.2</li.
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now let's say you want to apply a style to `<li>`s, but *not* the submenu. `.nav>li` works beautifully for this, whereas `.nav li` will style submenus too. An ignorant programmer might try to override it back with `.nav li li`, making the performance problem worse.